# Does Plotly support headline numbers?

Tags: python, plotly, dashboard

I'm looking to create a report/dashboard and I want to include a headline number on top.  For example, if the report is "Monthly Sales Report" I want the top line to be something like:

**$15,100** *new revenue booked this month*

And then various charts, tables, whatnot beneath.

I like a lot of Plotly's functionality, but I don't see a "big number" feature.  Am I missing it, or is it just not an option?  Any python alternatives you'd recommend?

**Example**

[image]

Comment: Could [this](https://plot.ly/python/text-and-annotations/) beuseful? Otherwise why don't you share a sketch of what you're looking forward

Comment: Not quite annotation, but more just one big number.  Added an example image.  What I'm looking for is the `81` on the left.

Comment: I recently read [this](http://pbpython.com/wine_visualization.html) with bokeh. Look for `desc.text` I don't know if it's possible to change font/size.